# How can get a flatten dataframe from a nested json containing arrays

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, flatten

I just started to code Spark with Scala, I'm trying to flatten a json as dataframe in order to writh in hadoop, I had some problem dealing with nested json cointaining arrays. Anybody as some suggestion in order to flat a json in a dataframe?

this is my schema:

```
root
 |-- Destination: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- DestinationId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MessageTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MessageVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sensors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Lat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Lng: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Measures: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- PropertyId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- SensorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- TransactionId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Lat: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Lng: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried the flattan function provided as a solution of several question

This is what i did:

```
val df2 = spark.read.json("message.json").toDF()

val dfPayload = df2.select(df2("Payload")).select("Payload.Type","Payload.TransactionId", "Payload.Sensors" )
val dfSensors = dfPayload.select(explode(dfPayload("Sensors"))).toDF("Sensors").select("Sensors.SensorId", "Sensors.Location.Lat", "Sensors.Location.Lng", "Sensors.Measures")
      //output
      dfSensors.show()
Sensors
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|SensorId|       Lat|       Lng|            Measures|
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+
|  S02001|43.5356278|10.2977402|[[DISPL, 2019-07-...|
|  S02002|43.1237824|10.0984567|[[DISPL, 2019-06-...|
|  S02003|43.0598432|10.9152361|[[TEMP, 2019-07-1...|
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+

      val dfMeasures = dfSensors.select(explode(dfSensors("Measures"))).toDF("Measures").select("Measures.Time", "Measures.PropertyId", "Measures.Value")
      //output
      dfMeasures.show()
Measures
+--------------------+----------+-----+
|                Time|PropertyId|Value|
+--------------------+----------+-----+
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|     DISPL|00.87|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|00.02|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.09|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCZ|00.03|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|     DISPL|00.92|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|00.69|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.21|
|2019-06-26T08:25:...|      ACCZ|00.95|
|2019-06-26T08:16:...|     DISPL|00.71|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|     DISPL|10.43|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|     DISPL|10.36|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|10.22|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.69|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCZ|00.81|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|00.22|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.49|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCZ|00.74|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|00.23|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.95|
|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCZ|00.90|
+--------------------+----------+-----+
```

I can explode the array but i loss the column of the father

I need a flatten dataframe containing exploded array as record and father columns, like this

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+
|SensorId|       Lat|       Lng|                Time|PropertyId|Value|
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+
|  S02001|43.5356278|10.2977402|2019-07-17T10:43:...|     DISPL|00.87|
|  S02001|43.5356278|10.2977402|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCX|00.02|
|  S02001|43.5356278|10.2977402|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCY|00.09|
|  S02001|43.5356278|10.2977402|2019-07-17T10:43:...|      ACCZ|00.03|
|  S02002|43.1237824|10.0984567|2019-06-26T08:25:...|      ACCZ|00.95|
|  S02003|43.0598432|10.9152361|2019-06-26T08:16:...|     DISPL|00.71|
+--------+----------+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+
```

Anybody as encountered the same problem;

Comment: You should include all the columns in select. Or you can use explode with withColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Column}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

//////////////////////// Flatten schema ////////////////////////
implicit class DataFrameHelpers(df: DataFrame) {
  def flattenSchema: DataFrame = {
    df.select(flattenStructs(Nil, df.schema): _*)
  }
  def removeColPrefix(prefix: String): DataFrame = {
    df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).as(c.replaceFirst(prefix,""))): _*)
  }
}

protected def flattenStructs(path: Seq[String], schema: DataType): Seq[Column] = schema match {
  case s: StructType => s.fields.flatMap(f => flattenStructs(path :+ f.name, f.dataType))
  case other => col(path.map(n => s"`$n`").mkString(".")).as(path.mkString("_")) :: Nil
}
```

Run like this:

```
val flattenedReaderDF = df2
  .select("Payload")
  .flattenSchema
```

If you don't want it to infer the schema, you can also pass the schema to it like so `.select(from_json($"Payload", schema)`

From there you can run `removeColPrefix`, and trim off anything you don't want like:

```
val flattenedReaderDF = df2
  .select(col("Payload"))
  .flattenSchema
  .removeColPrefix("Sensors_", "Location_", "Measures_")
```